# How to execute an await method after another await using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have code like below

```
const somePromises = values.map(({variable, value}) => 
    this.post('/api/values/', {
        variable,
        value,
        item: itemId,
    })
);
await Promise.all(somePromises);

if (somecondition) {
    params.var = var;
    await this.patch('/api/items/${itemId}/', params);
}
```

the above code works but i want to execute if clause only if there is values has some value or if somePromises is resolved.

so was trying something like below,

```
const somePromises = values.map(({variable, value}) => 
    this.post('/api/values/', {
        variable,
        value,
        item: itemId,
    })
);
await Promise.all(somePromises).then (() => {
    if (somecondition) {
    params.var = var;
    await this.patch('/api/items/${itemId}/', params); //but throws err here
}
});
```

but throws error await cant be used here and async should be used. how can i fix this issue.
could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `await` inside your callback function body. So, that callback function also should by `async` if you want to `await` inside it.

```
await Promise.all(somePromises).then(async () => {
    if (somecondition) {
        params.var = var;
        await this.patch('/api/items/${itemId}/', params);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `this.patch` returns a Promise, you can `return` it if it passes the conditions, or return a resolved Promise:

```js
Promise.all(somePromises).then(() => {
    if (somecondition) {
      return this.patch('/api/items/${itemId}/', params);
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(null);
    }
}).then(response => {
  if (response) {
  // do something with response, the returned value from this.patch
  }
});
```